# How can I keep track of total transaction amount sent from an account each last 6 month?

Tags: r, date, transactions, aggregate-functions, aggregation

This is my transaction data

```
data 

id          from    to          date        amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  700.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  600.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  1000.0
…           …       …           …           …
1055597     9866    9736        2010-12-31  278.9
1053519     9868    8644        2010-12-31  242.8
1052790     9869    8399        2010-12-31  372.2
```

Now for each distinct account in `from` column, I want to keep track of how much transaction amount they sent over last 6 month at the time the transaction was made and so I want to do it according to the transaction date at which the particular transaction was made.

To see it better I will only consider the account `5370` here. So, then let's consider the following data:

```
id          from    to          date        amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>
18529       5370    9356        2005-05-31  24.4
13742       5370    5605        2005-08-05  7618.0
9913        5370    8567        2005-09-12  21971.0
2557        5370    5636        2005-11-12  2921.0
18669       5370    8933        2005-11-30  169.2
35900       5370    8483        2006-01-31  71.5
51341       5370    7626        2006-04-11  4214.0
83324       5370    9676        2006-08-31  261.1
100277      5370    9105        2006-10-31  182.0
103444      5370    9772        2006-11-08  16927.0
```

The very first transaction `5370` made was on `2005-05-31`. So there's no any record before that. That's why this is the starting date point for `5370`(So, each distinct account will have their own starting date point based on which date they made their first transaction). Thus, total transaction amount sent by `5370` in last 6 month at that time was just 24.4. Going to the next transaction of `5370`, there comes the second transaction made on `2005-08-05`. At that time, total transaction amount sent by `5370` in last 6 month was `24.4 + 7618.0 = 7642.4`. So, the output should be as follows:

```
id          from    to          date        amount     total_trx_amount_sent_in_last_6month_by_from
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>      <dbl>
18529       5370    9356        2005-05-31  24.4       24.4 
13742       5370    5605        2005-08-05  7618.0     (24.4+7618.0)=7642.4
9913        5370    8567        2005-09-12  21971.0    (24.4+7618.0+21971.0)=29613.4
2557        5370    5636        2005-11-12  2921.0     (24.4+7618.0+21971.0+2921.0)=32534.4
18669       5370    8933        2005-11-30  169.2      (7618.0+21971.0+2921.0+169.2)=32679.2
35900       5370    8483        2006-01-31  71.5       (7618.0+21971.0+2921.0+169.2+71.5)=32750.7
51341       5370    7626        2006-04-11  4214.0     (2921.0+169.2+71.5+4214.0)=7375.7
83324       5370    9676        2006-08-31  261.1      (4214.0+261.1)=4475.1
100277      5370    9105        2006-10-31  182.0      (261.1+182.0)=443.1
103444      5370    9772        2006-11-08  16927.0    (261.1+182.0+16927.0)=17370.1
```

For the calculations, I subtracted 180 days(approx. 6 months) from the transaction date on each line. That's how I chose which amounts should be summed up.

So, how can I achieve this for the whole data, considering all the distinct accounts?

PS: My data has 1 million rows so the solution also should run faster on a large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way using `dplyr` could be :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  mutate(total_trx = purrr::map_dbl(date, 
                     ~sum(amount[between(date, .x - 180, .x)])))

#      id  from    to date        amount total_trx
#    <int> <int> <int> <date>       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  18529  5370  9356 2005-05-31    24.4      24.4
# 2  13742  5370  5605 2005-08-05  7618      7642. 
# 3   9913  5370  8567 2005-09-12 21971     29613. 
# 4   2557  5370  5636 2005-11-12  2921     32534. 
# 5  18669  5370  8933 2005-11-30   169.    32679. 
# 6  35900  5370  8483 2006-01-31    71.5   32751. 
# 7  51341  5370  7626 2006-04-11  4214      7376. 
# 8  83324  5370  9676 2006-08-31   261.     4475. 
# 9 100277  5370  9105 2006-10-31   182       443. 
#10 103444  5370  9772 2006-11-08 16927     17370.
```

---

If you are data is huge you can use the above approach in `data.table` which might be efficient.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, total_trx := sapply(date, function(x) 
                         sum(amount[between(date, x - 180, x)])), from]
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one also works very well.. It's been very helpful.

Comment: The first one is much faster but it creates some warnings, could you tell why?

Comment: Warnings are about "Unknown or uninitialised columns" which are caused by tibbles, but the output is correct.

Comment: I think you can ignore those warnings. Maybe restarting R Studio will fix it.

Comment: Can you please see my edit, I have one more question on this topic

Comment: You should not extend the question by editing it. Instead you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: But the question is directly related to this question. It's a part of it.

Comment: If the question is related you can add a link of this question in your next question. Every question should solve only one specific problem. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers

Comment: Thank you! I posted it as a new question