# How can I keep track of total transaction amount received by an account each last 6 month?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, datatable, sqldf

This is my transaction data. It shows the transactions made from the accounts in `from` column to the accounts in `to` column with the date and the amount information

```
data 

id          from    to          date        amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  700.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  600.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  1000.0
…           …       …           …           …
1056317     7819    7454        2010-12-31  60.2
1056318     6164    7497        2010-12-31  107.5
1056319     7533    7492        2010-12-31  164.1
```

Now what I want to do is as follows: I want to go over every transaction row by row and for each account in `from` column, I want to keep track of how much transaction amount they received over last 6 month at the time that particular transaction was made and want to save this information as a new column.(so this new column will describe total transaction amount received by the accounts in `from` column in the last six months prior to the transaction date.)

For example:
In the very first line of data, for account `6644`, I should look into the `to` column if `6644` got a transaction between the dates  `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"` which is a 6-month period up until the date `2005-01-01` which is the date when the transaction -we are at- is made by `6644`. If there are such transactions that `6644` received, I should sum up them and add this sum information to a new column `total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month` as a value. Similarly, I should do the same for account `6753`
and look for the transactions it got between the dates  `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"` and sum them up and add this sum to the column `total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month`.
And, I should continue in this manner row by row in data.

So, how can I achieve this for the whole data?

PS: In the date interval `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"`, `"2005-01-01"` is the transaction date, to get the second date `"2004-07-05"` I subtract 180 days(approx. 6 months) from the transaction date `"2005-01-01"`.

To see it better, I provide the following data:
I will also show how the output will be. Let's say we only have this many of transactions. Just consider `5370` account here, since other accounts `8605,6390,8934` don't receive any transactions here.

```
id          from    to          date        amount  total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month 
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>    <dbl>
18529       5370    9356        2005-05-31  24.4     0.0
13742       5370    5605        2005-08-05  7618.0   0.0
9913        5370    8567        2005-09-12  21971.0  0.0
956         8605    5370        2005-10-05  5245.0   0.0
2557        5370    5636        2005-11-12  2921.0   5245.0    
1602        6390    5370        2005-11-26  8000.0   0.0
18669       5370    8933        2005-11-30  169.2    (5245.0+8000.0)=13245
35900       5370    8483        2006-01-31  71.5     (5245.0+8000.0)=13245
48667       8934    5370        2006-03-31  14.6     0.0
51341       5370    7626        2006-04-11  4214.0   (8000.0+14.6)=8014.6
```

Here is what I did:
First note that this small data above is sorted by `date` in ascending order.
In the first line, for account `5370` in `from column` I look at the past data to see if `5370` received any transaction between the dates `"2004-12-02"-"2005-05-31"`. Since the first line is the very first transaction, obviously there's no transaction received by `5370` before the date `"2005-05-31"`, so I log `0.0` into the `total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month` column respectively. In the second line, for account `5370` in `from column`, again there's no transaction received by `5370` between the dates `"2005-02-06"-"2005-08-05"`, so I log `0.0` into the `total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month` column. Similarly, I log `0.0` in the 3rd and 4th lines for accounts `5370` and `8605` respectively. In the fifth line, for account `5370` in `from column`, there's a transaction received by `5370` between the dates `"2005-05-16"-"2005-11-12"`, which is received in `"2005-10-05"`(in the 4th line of the data) with the amount `5245.0` so I log `5245.0` into the `total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month` column. In the sixth line, for account `6390` in `from column`, there's no transaction received by `6390` between the dates `"2005-05-30"-"2005-11-26"`, so I log `0.0` into the `total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month` column.  And it goes like this for all the rows of the data.

dput() output of the data:

```
structure(list(id = c(18529L, 13742L, 9913L, 956L, 2557L, 1602L, 
18669L, 35900L, 48667L, 51341L, 53713L, 60126L, 60545L, 65113L, 
66783L, 83324L, 87614L, 88898L, 89874L, 94765L, 100277L, 101587L, 
103444L, 108414L, 113319L, 121516L, 126607L, 130170L, 131771L, 
135002L, 149431L, 157403L, 157645L, 158831L, 162597L, 162680L, 
163901L, 165044L, 167082L, 168562L, 168940L, 172578L, 173031L, 
173267L, 177507L, 179167L, 182612L, 183499L, 188171L, 189625L, 
193940L, 198764L, 199342L, 200134L, 203328L, 203763L, 204733L, 
205651L, 209672L, 210242L, 210979L, 214532L, 214741L, 215738L, 
216709L, 220828L, 222140L, 222905L, 226133L, 226527L, 227160L, 
228193L, 231782L, 232454L, 233774L, 237836L, 237837L, 238860L, 
240223L, 245032L, 246673L, 247561L, 251611L, 251696L, 252663L, 
254410L, 255126L, 255230L, 258484L, 258485L, 259309L, 259910L, 
260542L, 262091L, 264462L, 264887L, 264888L, 266125L, 268574L, 
272959L), from = c("5370", "5370", "5370", "8605", "5370", "6390", 
"5370", "5370", "8934", "5370", "5635", "6046", "5680", "8026", 
"9037", "5370", "7816", "8046", "5492", "8756", "5370", "9254", 
"5370", "5370", "7078", "6615", "5370", "9817", "8228", "8822", 
"5735", "7058", "5370", "8667", "9315", "6053", "7990", "8247", 
"8165", "5656", "9261", "5929", "8251", "5370", "6725", "5370", 
"6004", "7022", "7442", "5370", "8679", "6491", "7078", "5370", 
"5370", "5370", "5658", "5370", "9296", "8386", "5370", "5370", 
"5370", "9535", "5370", "7541", "5370", "9621", "5370", "7158", 
"8240", "5370", "5370", "8025", "5370", "5370", "5370", "6989", 
"5370", "7059", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9121", "5608", "5370", 
"5370", "7551", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9163", "9362", 
"6072", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370"), to = c("9356", 
"5605", "8567", "5370", "5636", "5370", "8933", "8483", "5370", 
"7626", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9676", "5370", 
"5370", "5370", "5370", "9105", "5370", "9772", "6979", "5370", 
"5370", "7564", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "8744", 
"5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", 
"5370", "5370", "7318", "5370", "8433", "5370", "5370", "5370", 
"7122", "5370", "5370", "5370", "8566", "6728", "9689", "5370", 
"8342", "5370", "5370", "5614", "5596", "5953", "5370", "7336", 
"5370", "7247", "5370", "7291", "5370", "5370", "6282", "7236", 
"5370", "8866", "8613", "9247", "5370", "6767", "5370", "9273", 
"7320", "9533", "5370", "5370", "8930", "9343", "5370", "9499", 
"7693", "7830", "5392", "5370", "5370", "5370", "7497", "8516", 
"9023", "7310", "8939"), date = structure(c(12934, 13000, 13038, 
13061, 13099, 13113, 13117, 13179, 13238, 13249, 13268, 13296, 
13299, 13309, 13314, 13391, 13400, 13404, 13409, 13428, 13452, 
13452, 13460, 13482, 13493, 13518, 13526, 13537, 13542, 13544, 
13596, 13616, 13617, 13626, 13633, 13633, 13639, 13642, 13646, 
13656, 13660, 13664, 13667, 13669, 13677, 13686, 13694, 13694, 
13707, 13716, 13725, 13738, 13739, 13746, 13756, 13756, 13756, 
13761, 13769, 13770, 13776, 13786, 13786, 13786, 13791, 13799, 
13806, 13813, 13817, 13817, 13817, 13822, 13829, 13830, 13836, 
13847, 13847, 13847, 13852, 13860, 13866, 13871, 13878, 13878, 
13878, 13882, 13883, 13883, 13887, 13887, 13888, 13889, 13890, 
13891, 13895, 13896, 13896, 13899, 13905, 13909), class = "Date"), 
    amount = c(24.4, 7618, 21971, 5245, 2921, 8000, 169.2, 71.5, 
    14.6, 4214, 14.6, 13920, 14.6, 24640, 1600, 261.1, 16400, 
    3500, 2700, 19882, 182, 14.6, 16927, 25653, 3059, 2880, 9658, 
    4500, 12480, 14.6, 1000, 3679, 34430, 12600, 14.6, 19.2, 
    4900, 826, 3679, 2100, 38000, 79, 11400, 21495, 3679, 200, 
    14.6, 100.6, 3679, 5300, 108.9, 3679, 2696, 7500, 171.6, 
    14.6, 99.2, 2452, 3679, 3218, 700, 69.7, 14.6, 91.5, 2452, 
    3679, 2900, 17572, 14.6, 14.6, 90.5, 2452, 49752, 3679, 1900, 
    14.6, 870, 85.2, 2452, 3679, 1600, 540, 14.6, 14.6, 79, 210, 
    2452, 28400, 720, 180, 420, 44289, 489, 3679, 840, 2900, 
    150, 870, 420, 14.6)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

(I turned `from` and `to` columns into character, since they had a huge number of levels the output would take so much space otherwise)

Comment: Why would this answer not work here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63689794/3962914 Instead of group by `from` you do it for `to` ?

Comment: Yes it works but after then I want to add the new column into the data in a way that it describes a feature of ‘from’ column. If we just group by ‘to’ and do the computation like in your solution, that new column will describe a feature of ‘to’ column. I create new columns based on ‘from’ column, so every other features in my data also describe a feature of ‘from’ column.

Comment: although we are doing computation considering `to` column but I think it is what you want unless I am confused. Can you check the output doing that and if it doesn't match your expectations can you update your post showing output of `to` column and your expected output with `from` ?

Comment: I manually showed how the output would be just above the dput output of the data. Have you seen that? I computed total_trx_amount_received_in_last_6month column based on ‘to’ column, but added that information based on ‘from’ column.

Comment: I explained how I did the computations, can you please check? I hope it's better now

Comment: dput does not generate reproducible output if there are pointer components. Convert it to a data frame first.  Also make it smaller but large enough to illustrate problem.

Comment: I did thanks @G.Grothendieck

Comment: Is it clear now? @RonakShah

Comment: How about this? `data %>% mutate(amt = map2_dbl(from, date, ~sum(amount[to == .x & between(date, .y - 180, .y)])))` . This is using `dplyr` and `purrr`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Could you please share this as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you!

Comment: Btw, instead of `sum` function, when I run `max` function, if the account has received any transaction in the specified time interval it returns the correct value, but if it hasn't it returns `-Inf` instead of `0` and prints lots of warnings like `Input amt is map2_dbl(...).no non-missing arguments to max; returning -InfProblem with mutate() input amt. x no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf` in the console. Whereas `mean` and `median` functions  just return `NAN` and `NA` respectively w/o warnings if the account hasn't received any transaction in the specified time interval

Comment: Yes, that is because it returns `numeric(0)` when there are no matches and `max(numeric(0))` returns `-Inf`.

Comment: That one answers about how much money sent by each account, here what I ask about is how much money is received by each account @E_net4thepostjanitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2_dbl` and take `sum` of `amount` that lie in the 6-month range.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
    mutate(amt = map2_dbl(from, date,
                ~sum(amount[to == .x & between(date, .y - 180, .y)])))
```

Comment: It works on a small data set very well, but when I try it on a large dataset, it seems that it will run forever

Comment: Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can translate the same code to base R and `data.table` but I am not aware about other way of doing this.

Comment: I tried to speed up the code with `future::plan(strategy = multisession)` and modified the code as `data[, amt := furrr::future_pmap_dbl(list(from, date), ~sum(amount[to== .x & between(date, .y-180, .y)])) ]`, but the speed hasn't been improved at all.